# 'oauth2: "invalid_grant" "Bad Request"' error when including scopes in Goth Google authorization

Tags: authentication, go, google-oauth

The following 2 files are for authorizing google users using "github.com/markbates/goth":
auth.go file:

```golang
package auth

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "github.com/markbates/goth"
    "github.com/markbates/goth/gothic"
    "github.com/markbates/goth/providers/google"
)

const (
    MaxAge = 86400 * 30
    IsProd = false
)

func NewAuth() {
    godotenv.Load(".env")

    key := os.Getenv("RANDOM_KEY")
    googleClientID := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
    googleClientSecret := os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET")

    store := sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(key))
    store.MaxAge(MaxAge)

    store.Options.Path = "/"
    store.Options.HttpOnly = true
    store.Options.Secure = IsProd

    gothic.Store = store

    goth.UseProviders(
        google.New(
            googleClientID, googleClientSecret, "http://localhost:8080/auth/google",
            // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
            // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.channel-memberships.creator",
            // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly",
        )
    )
}
```

handler_login.go file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
    "github.com/markbates/goth/gothic"
)

func (cfg *apiConfig) handlerAuthLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    provider := chi.URLParam(r, "provider")
    r = r.WithContext(context.WithValue(context.Background(), "provider", provider))
    if user, err := gothic.CompleteUserAuth(w, r); err == nil {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:5173", http.StatusFound)
        cfg.createUser(w, r, user)
        return
    } else {
        gothic.BeginAuthHandler(w, r)
    }
}
```

This code works fine, but if I include the scopes I want in my Google provider (that I have commented out in auth.go above), then I get an 'oauth2: "invalid_grant" "Bad Request"' error from my "CompleteUserAuth" function call in my login handler. I don't know why this only happens when I include the scopes, as they work for the authorization process as they should, it just seems to give this error when trying to get back a valid access token afterwards.

This error is happening with any Google scopes I try and use, not just YouTube ones, and I haven't had this issue with authenticating Twitch users using the same login handler.

Any help or advice on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I've since tried making a new issue on the goth GitHub page, but have not had any responses for a few days, and it looks as though the majority of recent ones don't get addressed at all.